# Understanding problems of code

Tags: java

I'm doing Project Euler and I got stuck at problem 3. After 2 hours of trying to make a java program in vain, I googled the answer but I can't understand a few things. Sorry if I ask stupid questions but I'm noob and I really want to learn.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long x = 600851475143L;
    long biggest = 0L;

    for (long i = 2L; i <= x; i++) { // <- HERE, WHY 2L and NOT 1L ?
        for (long l = 1L; l <= Math.sqrt(i); l++) { //  <-  HERE, why Math.sqrt(i) ?????
            if (l % i == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                while (x % i == 0) {
                    x = x / i; // <- Why x/i ???
                    biggest = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(biggest);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _Why_? Do you know what those things do? Do you know what a numerical literal is and what the syntax is for `long` literals? Do you know what a class is and what a `static` method is? Do you know what javadoc is? Do you know what integer division is? Those are all things you should now look up before proceding.

Comment: I know what they do but I can't really figure out what's with that math.sqrt thing. I was taught that if I want to check prime numbers to give divisor and increase it in for loop, if it has divisors has value 2 then it's prime else not and I don't get what this guy did

Comment: each question on project euler has a pdf that you can download once you enter the correct answer, it has explanations. that might be a good place to start.

Comment: @NathanHughes not every question has a pdf, but #3's is pretty good.

Comment: @newbiejava1998 I've pushed some of my Java code for project euler to www.github.com/mananshah99/project-euler. Feel free to check it out if you get stuck on any additional problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the text of [Problem 3 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3):

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

Knowing this, the first thing to know about prime factors is:

1. They must be a prime number.
2. 1 is not a prime factor.

Additional, the largest factor of a number cannot be higher than its square root.

By knowing these data, we can start working on our algorithm. The current solution proposes this:

```
//i are the possible factors for the number
for (long i = 2L; i <= x; i++) { // <- HERE, WHY 2L and NOT 1L ?
    //answer: because 1 is not the first possible prime factor, is 2
    for (long l = 1L; l <= Math.sqrt(i); l++) { //  <-  HERE, why Math.sqrt(i) ?????
        //answer: the largest factor of a number cannot be higher than its square root
        if (l % i == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            while (x % i == 0) {
                x = x / i; // <- Why x/i ???
                //if i is a factor of x, mark it as the current biggest factor
                biggest = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

---

Note that the square root of 600851475143 is 775146.09922..., rounded down to 775146, which means that you can reword the problem to: *What is the largest prime number lower than 775146 that is a factor of 600851475143?*. With this, you can try other algorithms to obtain the answer for the problem above.

One better solution would be getting the factors of 600851475143 starting from 775146 down to 2, then check if the factor is a prime number. The first factor that is prime will be the desired answer.